# The visibility for renderings of objects is switched off, but is still displayed for random frames in the viewport and for associated renderings

Tags: rendering, animation, visibility

I use an object (the sphere in the middle) exclusively as boolean for an animation and don't want it to be visible in the renderings. Therefore I have switched off "Show in Renders" in the "Visibility" and display the object in the viewport as a wire. This actually works very well, but randomly in frames 15, 16 (shown in image below) and 28 the object is displayed as solid in the viewport as well and more important in the rendered frames. I can't explain this at all and unfortunately I don't know what to do now.[image: Frames 14,15,16 and 17 in viewport + Visibility settings]

Comment: Do you have the object's camera icon disabled on the top-right Outliner panel? That won't stop it being displayed in the viewport but should prevent it ever being rendered.

Comment: please provide blend file because you even cutout the important part (outliner) in your provided screenshot

Comment: Hello Lara, welcome to BSE. It's possible, if the cut-out is animated, that the Boolean fails when edges exactly coincide, or other calculation limits are reached. Does the Boolean fail when you take those frames on their own?

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved the problem, not in the nicest way, but I rendered the animation as individual frames, and then moved the sphere slightly upwards in the frames where the invisibility did not work until it did and rendered the affected frames again individually.
Not the smoothest way, but the location adjustment was so small that you can't see it in the final animation.